# How to pass 2 radio selection value with a single Submit??

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

```
echo '<form method="post" action="mod_slots.php">';
 $i = 1;
 while(cond)
 {
 echo '<input type="radio" name="change1" value="'.$i.'" />';
 $i++;
 }

 $j = 1;
 while(cond)
{
  echo '<input type="radio" name="change1" value="'.$j.'" />';
 $j++; 
} 


}

  echo '<input type="submit" value="Change Selected" />';
  echo '</form>';
```

The above code passes only change1 value to the next page! But I want a single submit button, which will send both value!!?? 
My implementation may be wrong!

Comment: you can use `checkboxes` instead of `radio buttons`

Comment: actually the code is for replacing data from one set of data to other set.

Answer (score 1):

Radios with same name could only have one selection, if you want to divide them, just use different name.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can pass them by giving their names as **array** like

```
 echo '<input type="radio" name="change[]" value="'.$i.'" />';
```

and after submit you can print them like

```
print_r($_POST['change']);
```

Comment: should I use same variable or different?  Coz I am using 2 while loops

Comment: If they both are different loops,means for different data then you need to use two diff names

Comment: Ya theres the problem arises.. If I use 2 names then I will be needing 2 Submit, but I want just one submit to send both names!